# Inclusion from $S_1$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ is smooth.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I was asked to define explicitly a differentiable structure on $S_1$ such that the inclusion into $\mathbb{R}^2$ is smooth. I defined what I imagine to be the usual differentiable structure on $S_1$ as the atlas generated by the charts $(S_1\setminus\{(0,1)\}, \varphi_1)$ and $(S_1\setminus\{(0,-1)\}, \varphi_2)$ where $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are the homeomorphisms between these sets and $\mathbb{R}$ given by trig functions. (I hope these are smooth.)

I'm trying to show that with this structure the inclusion from $S_1$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a $C^\infty$ function. My definition of $C^\infty$ function between manifolds is that a function is $C^\infty$ if the pullback of any smooth function is a smooth function.

The result is very intuitive to me but I can't find a proof.

EDIT:

I've been hinted that better charts and homeomorphisms to use here are:

$$U_1 = \{ (x,y) \in S^1 \mid x > \frac12 \}$$
$$U_2 = \{ (x,y) \in S^1 \mid y > \frac12 \}$$
$$U_3 = \{ (x,y) \in S^1 \mid x < -\frac12 \}$$
$$U_4 = \{ (x,y) \in S^1 \mid y < -\frac12 \}$$

With projections to $x$ for $U_2$ and $U_4$ and projections to $y$ for $U_1$ and $U_3$.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which trig function you were thinking of for $\varphi_1$? And if so, can you compute a formula for $\varphi_1(x,y)$ when $(x,y) \in S^1$? And the same questions for $\varphi_2$.

Comment: @LeeMosher See my edit, thank you for your interest.

Comment: Those charts look good. So, now can you show that the inverse map of the projection on $U_1$, which is a function of the form $y \mapsto (x,y) \in U_1$, is a smooth function of the input variable $y$? And the same questions for the other charts.